# To return a percentage result from a boolean (True/False) Column using groupby in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to return a percentage (Pass) rate for some widgets (coloured either red, blue, green or purple).  I have added a column (Pass) to test if the widgets are in tolerance (13 to 14 inclusive), now using the groupby function I would like to return what percentage have passed by colour, I just don't know how to add this to my groupby function.  My code is:

```
#Create new series called Pass to test if in tolerance
widgets['Pass'] = widgets.Vals.between(13, 14, inclusive=True)
print(widgets.head(20))

#Group by Colours - blue, green, purple, red
#Give results - count, pass(%), mean, var
widgets = widgets.groupby('Colour').Vals.agg(['count', 'mean', 'var'])
print(widgets)
```

The result is:

```
            Vals  Colour   Pass
0   13.166671     red   True
1   13.844101     red   True
2   13.667672  purple   True
3   13.457526     red   True
4   13.512347     red   True
5   13.421277   green   True
6   13.692874     red   True
7   13.768719     red   True
8   13.489158    blue   True
9   13.487612    blue   True
10  13.611823  purple   True
11  14.193408     red  False
12  13.344894  purple   True
13  13.585790  purple   True
14  13.274137    blue   True
15  13.447983     red   True
16  13.766603    blue   True
17  13.711676  purple   True
18  13.514098    blue   True
19  13.326753     red   True
        count       mean       var
Colour                            
blue    11225  13.500443  0.064099
green   11014  13.504158  0.063477
purple  11143  13.496960  0.064687
red     16618  13.501518  0.062595
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# you can use a apply function to do your own calculations.

widgets.groupby('Colour')['Pass'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x)/len(x))
Out[289]: 
Colour
blue      1.000000
green     1.000000
purple    1.000000
red       0.888889
Name: Pass, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @allen, between the two answers I got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
widgets = widgets.groupby('Colour').Vals.agg({
    'mean': 'mean', 
    'var': 'var', 
    'count': 'count', 
    'pct': lambda x: widgets .Pass[x.index].sum()/x.count()
})
```

Comment: Thanks @heyu91, between the two answers I got it working :)